# FCM- different downstream messages on web

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to migrate from the legacy FCM HTTP API to AdminSdk to send my messages, and I noticed an issue-

Originally, I would send a data notification to a web service worker, which would look something like this-

```
data = {
         "key" : "value"
       }
```

Sending this using AdminSdk(after creating the WebPushConfig) results in my web downstream receiving a message of the format-

```
{
  "notification" : {
                       //notification stuff
                   },
  "data":{
             "key" : "value"
         }
}
```

This is generally fine, and is as per spec, but if I send a similar message using the Legacy FCM HTTP API endpoint `/send`, I get-

```
{
  "notification" : {
                       //notification stuff
                   },
  "data": {
              "gcm.notification.key" : "value"
          }
}
```

on the front end. This seems like a fairly niche discrepancy- considering that the AdminSdk calls the `/:send` v1 endpoint under the hood, it would result in the same prefix-less data field(without `gcm.notification`).

As such, I'd still have to make front-end changes if I want to continue using FCM, but I'd like to know if there's any documentation out there that covers this spec, or if someone has seen this behaviour previously.